# Toggle hide/show double click issue

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

I already check all over the internet  yet I can't figure it out.  Every time  it loads I have to click it twice  in order to show the element. I also tried to replace

```js
else {
   ​x.style.display = "none";
```

`none` to `block`. it works but doesn't go back. I hope you guys can help me Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you provide the entire JavaScript code or preferably the part where you're invoking `myFunction` ?

Comment: Your `if` statement is useless.

Comment: Checking CSS properties directly is [best avoided](/q/55071684/4642212). Instead, a CSS class should be used, e.g. `.cls { display: none; }`; then [`.classList.has("cls")`](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) to check for its existence, `.classList.toggle("cls", condition)` for setting the class iff `condition` is true, etc. Consider using the [`hidden` attribute](//developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/hidden) instead.

Answer (score 0):

What if we do this:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
x.style.display = "none";
function myFunction() {
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

And also please share you html too

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing is the styling between `css` styling and `inline` styling. If the display of yor element is controlled by css class initially, the value of `x.style.display` will be an empty string. So that `x.style.display === "none"` will be false and your else block will execute that will set `x.style.display = "none"` and now when you execute the function `x.style.display` is `none` hence your if block executes and the display will be set to `block`. That's why it works on second click.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are comparing an empty string in the `if` statement.
You can either set the `display` to `none` property via JS instead of CSS or modify your `if` statement. So, this should do the work

```
if (x.style.display === "none" || x.style.display === "")
```

But I strongly recommend you to try some other logic/method.